# Promise.then() executing before the promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, promise, discord, discord.js

I'm having a problem with promises. I have this code:

```
let line = hey.fetchBans().then(() => {
  myStuff();
  console.log(line);
});
```

The problem is that `myStuff()` executes before `fetchBans()` is resolved. I tried to see if that was the real problem logging `line`, and it prints `Promise { <pending> }`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide more information on what hey.fetchBeans does - i.e. its source code

Comment: *"The problem is that myStuff() executes before fetchBans() is resolved"* Not with the code above, if we assume `fetchBeans` returns the promise you're saying isn't resolved until after `myStuff` runs. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: I guess the promise-status gets updated _after_ the callbacks are called. You should take your expected values as parameters to the callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`line` is not the promise that `hey.fetchBans()` returned (and which did fulfill before your callback is called), it is the promise that `.then(…)` returned (and which will be resolved with the result value of the callback). It will always be pending inside that very callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I completely forgot all the Promises stuff -_-'